# Do you think that a Stack Exchange Android App would be useful?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

Of course, answering from a smartphone or tablet would be extremely inefficient, but reading the new questions or checking if your question has any answer or comment in such a device would be a good way to interact with Math SE.

Don't judge me from my reputation, it's just an idea.

Comment: I'm not a huge fan of the SEApp.

Comment: @AsafKaragila neither am I. MSE isn't great on mobile browsers but I'd take it over the SE App any day. The SE App just feels so.... cluttered and busy.

Comment: It doesn't render mathjax in the comment section for me

Comment: @TheEmperorofIceCream There is a "render MathJax" option one can tap on a comment.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I don't know. But [somebody thought so](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/01/stack-exchange-for-android-is-here/), and built it. ;-)

Comment: Ohh! I'm sorry, I looked for it and I didn't find it. I'll take a look to the app. Thank you very much!

Comment: You are welcome. By the way, there is also an [iPhone app](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/05/stack-exchange-for-iphone-is-here/).

Comment: And also an [iPad app](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/239250/help-us-test-the-new-stack-exchange-ipad-app) in the working.

Comment: Is it available on play store?